# Is there any way to put an invisible character at beginning of a string to change its sort order?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting

Is there any way to put a non printing or non obtrusive character at the beginning of a string of data in sqlserver. so that when an **order by** is performed,  the string is sorted after the letter z alphabetically?

I have used a space at the beginning of the string to get the string at the top of the sorted list, but I am looking to do something similar to put a string at the end of the list.

I would rather not put another field such as "SortOrder" in the table to use to order the sort, and I would rather not have to sort the list in my code.

Added: Yes I know this is a bad idea, thanks to all for mentioning it, but still, I am curious if what I am asking can be done

Comment: Sort on the substring?  I'm not clear about what you're envisioning

Comment: @OMG Ponies Here are example string values: one, two , *four*, three, apple. I would like them sorted as apple, one, three, two, and *four* .

Comment: I get the sorting part, I don't get how you intend on communicating that for sorting.  How do you know "four" is to be last?

Comment: @OMG Ponies Try this example of strings. I had used a formatting character in my previous example. Here are example string values: one, two , !four!, three, apple. I would like them sorted as apple, one, three, two, and !four! . – Lill Lansey

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since no one is venturing to answer your question properly, here's my answer

**Given:** You are already adding `<space>` to some other data to make them appear top

**Solution:** Add CHAR(160) to make it appear at the bottom. This is in reality also a space, but is designed for computer systems to not treat it as a word break (hence the name).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Your requirements:

1. Without adding another field such as "SortOrder" to the table
2. Without sorting the list in your code

I think this fits!

```
create table my(id int,data varchar(100))
insert my
select 1,'Banana' union all
select 2,Char(160) + 'mustappearlast' union all
select 3,' ' +N'mustappearfirst' union all
select 4,'apple' union all
select 5,'pear'

select *
from my
order by ASCII(lower(data)), data
```

<sub>(ok I cheated, I had to add `ASCII(lower(` but this is closest to your requirements than all the other answers so far)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You should use another column in the database to help specify the ordering rather than modifying the string:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable 
ORDER BY sortorder, yourstring
```

Where you data might look like this:

```
yourstring               sortorder
foo                      0
bar                      0
baz                      1
qux                      1
quux                     2
```

If you can't modify the table you might be able to put the sortorder column into a different table and join to get it:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable AS T1
JOIN yourtablesorting AS T2
ON T1.id = T2.T1_id
ORDER BY T2.sortorder, T1.yourstring
```

---

Alternative solution:

If you really can't modify the database at all, not even adding a new table then you could add any character you like at the start of the string and remove it during the select:

```
SELECT RIGHT(yourstring, LEN(yourstring) - 1)
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY yourstring
```

Comment: @Mark I think that's the best solution but the OP specifically said 'I would rather not put another field such as "SortOrder" in the table to use to order the sort,'

Comment: +1 Despite the OP's stated requirements, I still think this is the way to go.

Comment: @Skilldrick: Fair point! I didn't read that far... However I'd still recommend doing this. If the table can't be modified perhaps the column could be in a different table...

Comment: Other options that might make this more palatable: make the SortOrder a computed column. If the base table cannot be altered, create a view on the base table with the SortOrder column added in.

Comment: @Mark. Yes I know it is better to either sort by another column or do the processing in my code (I mentioned both possibilites in my question), but still, I am curious if what I am asking can be done.

Comment: @Mark - your `alternative answer` requires that an "intrusive character" be added to `every single record` for it to work properly, so it would be <space> for top, <other1> for rest and <other2> for bottom

Answer (score 1):

Could you you include something like:

```
"<SORT1>This is my string"
"<SORT2>I'd like this to go second"
```

And remove them later? I think using invisible characters is fragile and hacky.

Comment: +1 because this is a good idea. Small modification: it can be done in the same SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a sort order in the query and use unions (no guarantees on performance).

```
select 1 as SortOrder, *
from table
where ... --first tier
union
select 2, *
from table
where ... --second tier
order by SortOrder
```

Comment: This is the closest to what I was looking for so far.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, an invisible character for this purpose is a bad idea because it pollutes the data. I would do exactly what you would rather not do and add a new column.

To modify the idea slightly, you could implement it not as a sort order, but a grouping order, defaults to 0, where a negative integer puts the group at top of the list and a positve integer at the bottom, and then "order by sort_priority, foo"

Comment: of course, this is what mark described, but he hit post before me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm with everyone else that the ideal way to do this is by adding an additional column for sort order.

But if you don't want to add another column, and you already use a space for those items you want to appear at the top of the list, how do you feel about using a pipe (|) for items at the bottom of the list?

[By default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933426(v=sql.80).aspx), SQL Server uses a Unicode character set for its sorting.  In [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), the pipe and both curly brackets ({, }) come after z, so any of those three characters should work for you.

Comment: Starting with those special chars moved the string to the top of the sort.